# ThinkPad battery recalibration having no effect

Tags: battery, thinkpad, 18.10, tlp

ThinkPad T420s, Ubuntu 18.10. Running TLP.

If I run the battery as long as it can last, it goes at least two hours. Yet, Ubuntu (and "Power Statistics" app) think the battery can only last about ten minutes, with an apparent `Energy when full` value of `5.1 Wh` (down from original 39.0 Wh).

I've tried `tlp recalibrate` a few times now, and run the battery down myself manually a few more times, but over the last two weeks the only effect has been to reduce the `Energy when full` value from its previous `5.3 Wh`.

Yet, the battery still lasts far longer than Ubuntu thinks it can.

Am I missing something? How can I force the recalibration to take effect?